# Android GCM saying class not found (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GCM)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Android GCM saying `class not found (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GCM)`. I have put my google play-services in libs folder only. I have crossed checked it several times. Weird thing is its working in lollipop (API 21) but not working in jelly bean (API 17). Can any one please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Could you include the full error?

Comment: Try to use `Android studio` instead of `Eclipse`, and maybe your `emulator` without `Google Apis (Google Inc)` for API 17